# Batch file name string concatenation

Tags: string, batch-file, filenames, string-concatenation

this problem has been bothering me for hours. I hope someone could help shed some light. Basically, I am trying to scan through all the files (of a specific type) in a folder (there are no subfolder inside, so no need to worry this case), get those files' name, and concatenate all into one string for example, if a folder has two files,
a.xml, b.xml and c.xml, I want to get a string looks like

-a a.xml -a b.xml -a c.xml

Below is my code.

```
copy *.xml C:\FTP
setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion
set "directory=C:\temp"
set "attachment= "
set "a= -a "
for %%n in (%directory% *.xml) DO ( 
set "attachment=!attachment! %a% %directory%\%%n "
echo.%attachment%
)
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo.%attachment%
```

The output is shown in this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiw6p.jpg
the problem I have is that first, 
all echoes in the for loop prints out nothing. as shown in those blank lines.
the final string I want,i.e. attachment, contains an initial substring of

```
-a C:\temp\C:temp.
```

This is actually not a file. the final string I want should be one that is without this substring, only those behind it. By the way, if there is no file inside the folder, I want the string "attachment" to just an empty string like "".  Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside your `for` loop you show the value of `%attachment%`, so that value is NOT updated in each iteration; you must use delayed expansion to do so.

The set of values in `for` command is: `(%directory% *.xml)` that is, the value `C:\temp` and all files with .xml extension, that I assumed is none in current directory. After that, you use this value in `%a% %directory%\%%n` expression, so the result is `-a C:\temp\C:\temp`. I think there is not a point here.

If you want not the folder value in the list, just don't insert it and use `%~NXn` modifier in the `for` replaceable parameter.

Below is the correct code:

```
copy *.xml C:\FTP
setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion
set "directory=C:\temp"
set "attachment= "
set "a= -a "
for %%n in ("%directory%\*.xml") DO ( 
set "attachment=!attachment! %a% %%~NXn "
echo.!attachment!
)
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo.%attachment%
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! It works. Could I ask what is the difference btween echo.%attachment% and echo.!attachment!, and also what is %%~NXn ? Batch file seems to have so many abbreviations like, I am really blurred. Where can I find a list of these abbreviations? Thank you.